# Pass arguments to function

Tags: r, arguments

I have an understanding problem with passing arguments to a function in R.

In the following example, I retrieve a value from a named list by name. When I do it directly, it returns the value. But when I put the same code into a function, it returns NULL. What happens here?

Thanks in advance,
Mirko

```
namedlist <- list(a=c("50", "80"), b=c("50")) 

namedlist$a
# returns: [1] "50" "80"

myfunction <- function(arg){ namedlist$arg }
myfunction(a)
# returns: NULL
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are requesting:

`namedlist$arg`

and of course there isn't a component with the name `"arg"` in `namedlist`, hence the return value `NULL`.

this type of subsetting the list will work:

```
myfunction <- function(arg) {
    namedlist[[arg]]
}
```

and returns the same as namedlist$a, but you do need to pass the component name as a string:

```
> namedlist$a
[1] "50" "80"
> myfunction(a)
Error in myfunction(a) : object 'a' not found
> myfunction("a")
[1] "50" "80"
```

Comment: @Mirko in addition, you are relying here on scoping finding something in the global workspace. It would be better practice to write `myfunction` such that it is self-contained and you pass in all objects required as arguments. `myfunction <- function(list, arg)` and have the following as the function body `list[[arg]]`, and call it via `myfunction(namedlist, "a")`

Comment: I deleted mine, yours is more complete :)