# Use a function of the data in dplyr::summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

Assume I have a function of a data.frame which gives a single number back, now I would like to use the `summarise` in `dplyr` where the new variable should be this function applied for the data.frame grouped by another variable.

This is a stupid example

```
df <- data.frame(id=rep(c("A","B"),each=5),diff=rnorm(10))

func<-function(data){
  mean(data$diff)
}
```

I know this example is easily done using `summarise(Mean = mean(diff))`, but the points is not solving this example but in general using `summarise` with a function of a data.frame

My try so far has been

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(New = func(.))
```

but it gives the same value for every group, which is the overall function.

Hope everything is clear.

Comment: What is better to use?

Comment: Why can't it be `func <- function(col) mean(col); df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(New = func(diff))` or use `[` to subset the data

Comment: @akrun Why is it not good to use `$` inside functions?

Comment: It is not evaluated correctly

Comment: @akrun Because in general it will be a function of more columns

Comment: @akrun Could you please be more specific? I am not aware of any problems and have extensively used `$` inside functions without incident and would like to know what exactly could go wrong.

Comment: @akrun You can edit the question if you want

Comment: @zwol There are cases where it would not work.  For example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657466/pass-arguments-to-function/4657629#4657629)

Comment: @akrun That is a different thing, in the example is trying to subset the dataframe by the argument of the function, which is not our case

Comment: @adiana How about using your function(without any change) in `do` i.e. `df %>% group_by(id) %>% do(data.frame(New=func(.)))`

Comment: @akrun It was just on observation, you don't have to feel offended. Anyway, should I change with `mean(data["diff"])`?

Comment: No, I am not offended or anything.  I just said that in a meaningful way.  You should use the functions that works better for you.  Regarding the `summarise`, usinng your function, it is only going to evaluate the whole column instead of the subdatasets for each id.  I think `do` would suit that function.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking to use `summarise` is because inside the `summarise` I summarise other variables as well. In your case, do you know if there is a way to summarise other variables or with `do` I can just summarise one?

Comment: I think you have to change the function to make it work for summarise as I mentioned earlier.  With `do`, you can summarise other variables as well, but without showing what you wanted, it is not easy to comment.

Comment: @akrun I do not see how "the right argument of `$` is interpreted as a literal, not a variable" equates to "`$` is not evaluated correctly inside functions".

Comment: Just to have an idea, how do you add the computation of other things like the `sd`, using do?

Comment: @akrun @zwol Probably adding a new question about the good or bad practise of using `$` inside a function can help?

Comment: @zwol I meant if the data is also used as argument for function, it is not correctly interpreted.  I generally use a function not for a particular dataset alone.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, and I'm not familiar with the differences between the `plyr` and `dplyr` packages. The most straightforward way to do what I think you're trying to do is with `daply`:

```
> daply(df, .(id), func)
         A          B 
-0.0301488  0.2088815
```

Comment: It works, but the original question was with `dplyr`, is there a way to do it with `dplyr::summarise`?

Comment: I'm summarising several variables and I have used `summarise` so far, I wouldn't like to change all my code to the `daply` logic

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP states explicitly that they want to use dplyr. There are of course several alternatives to dplyr (some as efficient, some not), but that's not what OP is asking. -1

Comment: @zwol No, the question says `dplyr::summarise`

Comment: They are talking about `dplyr::summarise`. Different package, different function. Look at the question tags!

Comment: @Roland Like I said, I saw `dplyr` and assumed that that was a typo for `plyr`.

Comment: @Roland critiquing the answer because it's not efficient or it doesn't get the result the OP is looking for is one thing, but critiquing because they used a different package is silly. There is no reason OP shouldn't reconsider their package choice for this task or be stuck with one package only (a very strange hole I see a lot of `dplyr` users dig themselves into). The point of doing tasks using computers is to DO them, not to do them in this particular way only.

Comment: @eddi My assumption is that the point of the whole question is to understand how to do this within the dplyr paradigm. Otherwise this is surely a duplicate, i.e. standard mean by group FAQ.

Comment: @Roland somewhat arbitrary assumption - I don't see OP mentioning that they know how to do it using a different package; and even if they did - I've had many experiences where challenging OP's assumptions of the "right way to do things" has been very useful for the OP

Comment: @eddi I don't understand how that assumption can be arbitrary if the question is tagged [tag:dplyr].

Comment: @Roland seriously? I guess we should all stop answering questions if our answer introduces a package not tagged in OP.

Comment: @eddi Seriously, we should refrain from writing answers suggesting other packages if the question text is asking about a specific package functionality and the question has a corresponding tag. To give an extreme example: Sure, you can suggest in a comment that this can be done easier with python, but the answers should be using R.

Comment: @Roland that's an awful awful way to program in R - that's just not how the language works, sorry. And if you think limiting OP's horizons is helping them, then I don't think you understand the purpose of SO. And yes, if you think the task can be done easier with python, **including** the conversion of existing data/process to/from python, then absolutely you should give that answer.

Comment: @eddi As Roland is correctly pointing out, I'm able to perform the task in another package, but I want to use `dplyr::summarise` as I am already using `summarise` for performing other tasks with the same data.

Comment: @eddi Let's agree to disagree. How this answer can be a valid answer to a question stating that the goal is not solving a specific task, but about "in general using [dplyr's] summarise with a function of a data.frame" is beyond my understanding.

Comment: @Roland the goal *is* solving a specific task, they're not having a theoretical discussion, and the task is "complex summarizing of data, together with using a function". OP may indeed be thinking your extra narrow interpretation, but that is the nature of asking questions and something answers can help with. Imo it's a perfectly valid critique of this answer to say that this answer doesn't do that, but it absolutely isn't a valid critique saying this answer doesn't use `packageXYZ::functionOHMY`.

Answer (score 3):

As akrun pointed out in the comments, you can do this using `do` in `dplyr`:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% do(data.frame(New=func(.)))
```

You can also add other variables, though you have to use `.$`:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% do(data.frame(New=func(.), SmthElse = sd(.$diff)))
#  id        New  SmthElse
#1  A  0.1934552 1.0932424
#2  B -0.4161216 0.4841031
```

That said, the simpler and faster performance solution is using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(df) # or convert in place using setDT

dt[, .(New = func(.SD), SmthElse = sd(diff)), by = id]
#   id        New  SmthElse
#1:  A  0.1934552 1.0932424
#2:  B -0.4161216 0.4841031
```